# How to access other columns of has_many through table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on rails 7 with 2 models which are `Partner` and `Package`, and I would like to assign the packages to the partner, but they need to be assigned together with their orders.

For example, if I assign package#A and package#B to the partner with 1st and 2nd order respectively, then package#A will be considered as a small package and package#B will be considered as a medium package.

So, I have created `PartnerPackage` to link them together (with `has_many through:`) and also added `package_order` column to contain the package's order.

**Question**

What is the best way to retrieve all of the packages that belong to a specific partner, and also `package_order` as well? Thank you so much for your answer!

**Partner.rb**

```rb
class Partner < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :partner_packages, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :packages, through: :partner_packages
end
```

**Package.rb**

```rb
class Package < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :partner_packages, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :packages, through: :partner_packages
end
```

**PartnerPackage.rb**

```rb
class PartnerPackage < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :partner
  belongs_to :package

  validates :package_order, presence: true
end
```

Comment: `Partner.find(1).join(:packages)` should give you something to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a virtually hidden feature of Rails that allows you to add any other columns to an SQL select and Rails makes them available as readonly attributes in the resulting object, eg:

```
[24] pry(main)> ff = Foo.select("*, current_timestamp as now").first
  Foo Load (0.3ms)  SELECT *, current_timestamp as now FROM "foos" ORDER BY "foos"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Foo:0x0000000106442580 id: 1, name: "First Foo", age: 1, created_at: Thu, 21 Jul 2022 00:13:26.758228000 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Thu, 11 Aug 2022 15:23:14.015000000 UTC +00:00>
[25] pry(main)> ff.now
=> "2022-08-18 16:40:25"
```

So then you can use this to pull out the fields in a hmt table because you know that the SQL will include a join on that table:

```
partner.packages.select("packages.*, partner_packages.package_order")
```

Now if you want to get fancy you can use `Arel` to avoid the string table names, but that's the basic idea.

Comment: Thank you so much and sorry for the late replay. I got some error from your solution, but I get what you were trying to explain about `select`. I ended up using `partner.packages.select(Package.column_names, :package_order)` and it works!

Comment: Sorry, yeah, should have been `packages.*` instead of `partners.*` - I'll update it.